# Definition of Continuity in Non Standard Analysis (Internal Set Theory)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, set-theory, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

In Alain M. Robert's book, he affirms that continuity is implicitly defined by S-continuity and give the following example: Let $I$ be a standard interval and $\mathcal{F}$ be the space of numerical functions on $I$ (hence $\mathcal{F}$ is standard too). Then, for a $f \in \mathcal{F}$, we could define continuity at $x$ using the Standardization Axiom.

$f$ is continuous at $x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(f,x) \in \{(f,x) \in \mathcal{F} \times I: \text{$f$ is S-continuous at $x$} \}^S$

The problem with this definition is that the interval $I$ must be standard in order to the set $\mathcal{F}\times I$ be standard too, since a standard set is required by the Standardization Axiom. But continuity is a general concept that should be applied to functions defined at non-standard intervals too (e.g: $I = [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ with $\epsilon > 0$ infinitesimal and $f(x) = x$ makes $f$ continuous at $0$). So how the preceding definition can be fixed in order to include all definable functions $f: I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Set $\mathcal{C} = \{(f,J) \in \mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}): \text{$J$ is an interval, $f$ is defined on $J$, and $f$ is S-continuous at every $x \in J$} \}^S$.

Then an arbitrary real function $f\in \mathcal{F}$ is continuous on an arbitrary interval $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ precisely if $(f,J) \in \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Could I define $\mathcal{F}$ = $\bigcup_{I \subset \mathbb{R}} \mathcal{F}(I;\mathbb{R})$ as the set of all real functions and then define: $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $(f,x) \in \{(f,x) \in \mathcal{F}\times \mathbb{R}: \text{$f$ is defined at $x$ and $f$ is S-continuous at $x$ }\}^S$ ?

Comment: Assuming that "element of $\mathcal{F}$" is really all that you mean by *real function*, of course you can. The set of pairs you define is a standard set, whose standard elements are precisely all the pairs $(f,x)$ so that the standard function $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is S-continuous at the standard point $x$. But a standard real function is S-continuous at a point inside its domain precisely if it is continuous at that same point. So the standard set you defined is simply the set of all continuous real functions.